# Ubuntu Server several network ip config?

Tags: server, ip, ifconfig, ip-address

I have one ubuntu server
and i want config that with several IP address!
is it possible or no? 
if yes how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

copy your ifcfg-eth0 file to ifcfg-eth0:1 then ifcfg-eth0:2 etc, and change the device name to match eth0:1, and eth0:2 etc

Also change the ip address and other details.  Then restart your network service.

Note that you cannot have multiple default gateways like this.